# Creating Latex flashcards with python

Tags: python, automation

My goal is create a list of Definitions, Tehorems, Propositions from a given Latex file and send create new text files with them. Also, I want to create
First I import the file, then I split it based on a few Keywords like Definition and Theorem. The problem is that it doesen't split correctly and I don't know why.
Here is the link for the text file: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dkzddmwxrmbk

Here is the code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import io



def read_file(filepath):
    with io.open(filepath, 'r') as tmp:
        inhalt = tmp.read()
    return inhalt


#The method seperated_by_Keyword takes the string 'content' and k.
# 'content' contains the document that we want to split. k gives us the keyword that we use for the splitting.
def seperated_by_Keyword(content,k):
    Keyword = ['Definition.','Theorem.','Proposition.', 'Lemma.', 'Corollary.','Remark.','Examples.', 'Example.']
    flashcards=[Keyword[k]+Karten for Karten in content.split(Keyword[k]) ]

    seperated_by_keyword=[]
    for i in range(len(Keyword)):
        if i==k:
            continue
        for x in flashcards:
            d=x.split(Keyword[i])
            flashcards.extend(d)
            flashcards.remove(x)



#Here for the case of proofs we want to split them from their respective theorems and then add them to flashcards at the end.
    for x in flashcards:
        if 'Proof.' in x and x.startswith('Proof.')==False: # Here want want to ensure that we have something like flashcard of the form Theorem ....Proof. ...
            tmp=x.split('Proof.')
            flashcards.append(tmp[0])
            tmp[1]='Proof.'+tmp[1]
            flashcards.append(tmp[1])
            flashcards.remove(x)


    for j in range(len(flashcards)):
        flashcards[j] = '[latex]' + flashcards[j] + '[latex]'


    #We only want to take the flashcards that we chose via k. The
    for x in flashcards:
        if x.startswith('[latex]'+Keyword[k]):
            seperated_by_keyword.append(x)


    return seperated_by_keyword


def createNewFiles(Karteikarten):
    iterations_Array=[]
    for i in range(len(Karteikarten)):
        iterations_Array.append(i)
    for i in iterations_Array:
        if  Karteikarten[i].startswith('[latex]Proof.'):
            with open('{}Beweis.txt'.format(i-1), 'w') as f:
                f.write(Karteikarten[i])
        else:
            with open('{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as f:
                f.write(Karteikarten[i])

#Kopiert nach Karteikarten Excel





if __name__ == '__main__':
    inhalt=read_file('C:/Users/MueidSamad/Automators/Desktop/AMD.txt')
    flashcards=seperated_by_Keyword(inhalt,0)
    createNewFiles(flashcards)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't split correctly"?  What is the *first* line of your code that does not do what you expected?

Comment: When I run the code. It creates all the files I want. However, when I open the files I see that it contains the Definition part and the Proposition (in some files examples) part. It did not use the examples keyword to split it away.